# React router server side build issue

Tags: build, server, webpack, rendering, react-router

I am trying to deploy my react application and it is soo much harder than I initially thought.. 
Well, I´ve followed this guide: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering and it does not work.

I get this error message:

```
ERROR in ./modules/routes.js
Module parse failed: /Users/Alfred/React/newReactWebpack/reactWebpack/modules/routes.js Unexpected token (17:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (17:2)
```

I feel like I am totally unable to debug this at this point because of the fact that I have no idea how the **webpack.server.config.js** file works, nor the **webpack.config.js** file.

So I am looking for a webpack wizard who can help me with this. I would appreciate it a TON!

Thanks in advance!

---

**webpack.server.config.js**

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {

  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.js'),

  output: {
    filename: 'server.bundle.js'
  },

  target: 'node',

  // keep node_module paths out of the bundle
  externals: fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')).concat([
    'react-dom/server', 'react/addons',
  ]).reduce(function (ext, mod) {
    ext[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod
    return ext
  }, {}),

  node: {
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' }
    ]
  }

}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

// List of allowed environments
const allowedEnvs = ['dev', 'dist', 'test'];

// Set the correct environment
let env;
if (args._.length > 0 && args._.indexOf('start') !== -1) {
  env = 'test';
} else if (args.env) {
  env = args.env;
} else {
  env = 'dev';
}
process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV = env;

/**
 * Build the webpack configuration
 * @param  {String} wantedEnv The wanted environment
 * @return {Object} Webpack config
 */
function buildConfig(wantedEnv) {
  let isValid = wantedEnv && wantedEnv.length > 0 && allowedEnvs.indexOf(wantedEnv) !== -1;
  let validEnv = isValid ? wantedEnv : 'dev';
  let config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/' + validEnv));
  return config;
}

module.exports = buildConfig(env);
```

**server.js**

```
// ...
// import some new stuff
import React from 'react'
// we'll use this to render our app to an html string
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
// and these to match the url to routes and then render
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from './modules/routes'

// ...

// send all requests to index.html so browserHistory works

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
    // in here we can make some decisions all at once
    if (err) {
      // there was an error somewhere during route matching
      res.status(500).send(err.message)
    } else if (redirect) {
      // we haven't talked about `onEnter` hooks on routes, but before a
      // route is entered, it can redirect. Here we handle on the server.
      res.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
    } else if (props) {
      // if we got props then we matched a route and can render
      const appHtml = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>)
      res.send(renderPage(appHtml))
    } else {
      // no errors, no redirect, we just didn't match anything
      res.status(404).send('Not Found')
    }
  })
})

function renderPage(appHtml) {
  return `
    <!doctype html public="storage">
    <html>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <title>My First React Router App</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=/index.css>
    <div id=app>${appHtml}</div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
   `
}

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Production Express server running at localhost:' + PORT)
})
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base public/ --history-api-fallback",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && node server.bundle.js",
    "build:client": "webpack",
    "build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server"
  },
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

import LandingPage from '../src/compositions/landingPage/LandingPage'
import Webshop from '../src/compositions/webshopPage/Webshop'
import Gallery from '../src/compositions/galleryPage/Gallery'
import Services from '../src/compositions/servicesPage/Services'
import Checkout from '../src/compositions/checkoutPage/Checkout'
import Faq from '../src/compositions/faq/Faq'
import Products from '../src/components/webshop/products/Products'
import Product from '../src/components/webshop/products/Product'
import WebshopHome from '../src/compositions/webshopPage/WebshopHome'
import Admin from '../src/compositions/adminPage/Admin'
import Login from '../src/compositions/adminPage/Login'

module.exports = (
  <Route path="/" component={LandingPage}>
    <Route path="webshop" component={Webshop}>
      <IndexRoute component={WebshopHome}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/webshop/checkout" component={Checkout}></Route>
      <Route path="/webshop/:category" component={Products}></Route>
      <Route path="/webshop/:category/:subcategory" component={Products}></Route>
      <Route path="/webshop/:category/:subcategory/:product" component={Product}></Route>
    </Route>

    <Route path="gallery" component={Gallery}></Route>
    <Route path="services" component={Services}></Route>

    <Route path="login" component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path="admin" component={Admin} onEnter={requireAuth}>
      <Route path="/admin/:site" component={Admin}></Route>
      <Route path="/admin/:site/:section" component={Admin}></Route>
      <Route path="/admin/:site/:section/:category/:subcategory" component={Admin}></Route>
    </Route>

    <Route path="faq" component={Faq}></Route>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}></Route>
  </Route>
)
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import firebase from 'firebase/app'
require('firebase/auth')

import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import routes from '../modules/routes'
import store from './store/store'

//Initialize firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: ***********
  authDomain: **********
  databaseURL: **********
  storageBucket: **********
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

const app = document.getElementById('app')
const NotFound = () => (<h4 style={{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 100}}>404.. Oops, nu hamnade du fel!</h4>)

function requireAuth(nextState, replace, callback) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (null === user) {
      replace({
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
      })
      callback()
    }
    callback()
  })
}

render(
  (<Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}>
    </Router>
  </Provider>), app)
```

Comment: You're running everything through a jsx parser, right? Since your files don't have that ending you might not.

Comment: Hmm okey, where in the code do I change that?